# Obtener valor de la fila <th> en una table con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Buenas Tardes tengo la siguiente pregunta, supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

como hago para obtener con jquery el nombre de la columna (Month o Savings)

Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Sólo quieres obtener el nombre de la columna?

Comment: Como tal la columna no tiene nombre, pero supongo que te refieres a los valores en la columna. Además tienes que aclarar como deseas obtener los valores en esa columna. ¿Quieres listar todos o solamente una fila en especifico? Si es una fila especifica ¿en base a un click o un boton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bastante simple, como si tuvieras que aplicar estilos a esos mismos elementos del DOM.

```
// Aplico un ciclo para recorrer todos los elementos del tag th
$('table tr:first th').each(function() {
  // Obtengo el valor de dicho th
  var value = $(this).text();
  // Acá deberías hacer lo que quieras con ese valor obtenido
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Excelente.

Comment: De nada, no olvides de marcar como resuelto el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno a ver si te entendí, basta con agregar ids, seleccionarlos y obtener su valor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="column1">Month</th>
            <th id="column2">Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
<script>    
    var $column1 = $("#column1").text();
    console.log("column1: " + $column1);
    var $column2 = $("#column2").text();
    console.log("column2: " + $column2);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: En realidad , no es muy recomendable hacerlo de esa manera que por cualquier mantenimiento a la tabla , ese código jquery quedará inservible, la respuesta de arriba es mas acertada.